Determining Decennial Population using tidycensus
I want to get the total population by state for as many US decennial census as possible(e.g., 2020, 2010, 2000, etc.). The example below works fine for 2020 but not, for example, for 2010.
I know the proper code to run (see below) but how do I determine the variable name(s) for past decennials? I know how to use the load_variables() function but again, I don't know what data set variable to use for that function to pull up the variables available.
  pop20 <- get_decennial(
  geography = "state",
  variables = "P1_001N",
  year = 2020
)

I want it to match this from the US Census website for each census.
